# A clarification on $NP=coNP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

If we have two $NP$ complete problems $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ such that yes instances of $\Pi_1$ are no instances of $\Pi_2$ and vice versa then we know $NP=coNP$.

> 1. Is the converse true as well?
>
>    That is if $NP=coNP$ then can we find two $NP$ complete problems $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ such that yes instances of $\Pi_1$ are no instances of $\Pi_2$ and vice versa?

Note for $NP=coNP$ it suffices that all instances of $NP$ complete and $coNP$ complete problems have short certificates and it is not apriori clear if we can find $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$.

> 2. Does any $\Pi_1$ that is $NP$ complete work? If $\Pi_1$ is $NP$ complete then $\Pi_1^c$ (complement) is also $NP$ complete (since $NP=coNP$) and so does taking $\Pi_2=\Pi_1^c$ work?
>
>    Can we get other non-trivial pairs of $NP$ complete problems which are complementarily paired?

Comment: Such that yes-instances are no-instances and vice versa - that’s exactly complimentarity and everything else trivially follows.

Comment: @Eugene Can we get other non-trivial pairs of NPNP complete problems which are complementarily paired?

Comment: @Eugene's answer is the correct one.  You should write it as an answer that should be accepted.